# "Method used for the analysis of tissue aging" or "method used for tissue aging analysis"

Tags: adjectives

What sounds better / clearer?

"Method used for the analysis of tissue aging" or "method used for tissue aging analysis"

Or even

"Method used for the analysis of aging tissue " or "method used for aging tissue analysis"

Thanks!

Comment: In recent decades, the collocation ***tissue aging*** [has become significantly more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tissue+aging%2Caging+tissue&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctissue%20aging%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caging%20tissue%3B%2Cc0) than ***aging tissue***. Probably because more people are now writing about the former (the ***process*** of undergoing aging), as opposed to the latter (the ***substance*** which is undergoing that process). Your choice of "head noun" there just depends exactly ***what*** you're analysing.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer "method used for tissue aging analysis" for a headline or essay title or whatnot since it is terser than the alternative.

However, that phrasing does present an ambiguity: are we discussing a particular way of going about analyzing tissue aging, or are we discussing an analysis of some method used to age tissue? Still, I think the latter interpretation is sufficiently difficult to come up with to allow "method used for tissue aging analysis" to be okay for use in a headline or title.

But in order to lay to rest the ambiguity, it probably wouldn't hurt to go with the more long-form "method used for the analysis of tissue aging" in the text itself (say, the intro to the essay).

I would leave to you whether "tissue aging" or "aging tissue" is more appropriate. As FumbleFingers points out, that would depend on whether your analysis is of the process of tissue aging or of tissue that happens to be getting older, respectively.